# What are the facebook api limitations?

Tags: facebook, api

And where can I find more information on them?

I have looked but cannot find anything, so I am assuming there are none?

("limitations" related to limitations on how many times per second/minute/hour/day that you can "hit" their API)

Comment: are you talking about rate limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly limitations.

For example, you can't gather the e-mail addresses of someone's friends when that person has given permission to use your Facebook app. You also can't get all the fans of a Facebook page (it was possible in the past, but it no longer seems possible now) as it can easily be abused for spamming. Not all limitations are clearly mentioned in the documentation so you'll just have to try and see.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added the following text to my question: "limitations" related to limitations on how many times per second/minute/hour/day that you can "hit" their API.